# Robot focus in minimized frame

Tags: java, focus, awt, awtrobot

I'm using at the moment the `Robot` class of the AWT library for a Java `Frame`.

But when I minimize the frame, the robot will still type and using the mouse in another application that isn't even written in Java.

How can I set the focus on the frame only and when I minimize, it'll still continue?

Comment: That's the whole point of `Robot`. It would be a lot less useful if it could only affect Java programs.

Comment: There should be a way to focus it on a JFrame?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You want to robot to type to a minimized Java frame or what?

Comment: @9PP No, there shouldn't. It focuses on nothing, it moves the mouse and controls the keyboard, it doesn't care about anything that's happening underneath.

Comment: If I minimize the frame, the mouse and keybord should still work on the frame and not on the thing I focus on...                              This to automate my program while doing something else.

Comment: The Java `Robot` takes control of your keyboard and mouse. You cannot, by definition, do something else while Robot is running.

Comment: How would I make a virtual mouse and keybord in Java and do with my own mousr other stuff?

Comment: You will need to fire mouse events and keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set the focus on the frame only and when I minimize, it'll still continue?

You can't.  By design a minimized frame does not have, and cannot get, focus.

You might be able to 'hack it' by making the frame go almost transparent when asked to minimize, though that will block input to any window that is behind it, and will fail if another is in front.

Answer (score 1):

> That's the whole point of Robot. It would be a lot less useful if it could only affect Java programs. – Kayaman May 12 '15 at 6:06

That's right. Robot only 'controls', you need to provide logic like 'If Frame minimized, click the minimized icon' to the Robot.

But this involves a whole set of new questions:

- How do you know the Frame is minimized? (Sikuli)
- What is the coordinate for the minimized icon? (Sikuli)

After you at least answered these two questions, you can control the Robot to have your Frame back and continue with your GUI Automation.

The answers are in the brackets.